# Should the LINQ datacontext be stored in request.items for web apps?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Should the LINQ datacontext be stored in request.items for web apps?

Comment: Do you mean HttpContext.Items?

Comment: yes that is the items collection i'm referring too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, IMO. In particular, I'm quite a purest, so I don't think my UI should have **anything** to do with the data access. That is the job of a repository class. An a repository class should likewise have nothing to do with the http-request.

So by separation-of-concerns, the only logical answer here is "no".

---

Re being expensive (comments); it actually *gains* cost the longer you use it:

- the object/identity tracker will slowly accumulate each unique record you fetch
- the change tracker has more work to monitor
- you get a lot more chance of stale (out-of-date) records (getting wrong data is a definite cost)

And by allowing it to live beyond the DAL, you also have to worry about threading (this is especially true for web-requests, where you can get all *sorts* of interesting combinations of requests for the same session).

LINQ-to-SQL doesn't offer much cache; it has *limited* support to short-circuit identity lookups to the identity manager (so if you ask for `Single(x=>x.Id == 12345)`, and it has seen record `12345`, it won't hit the database). However, most of the time it'll hit the database. And re the database, one of the bigger costs there is the cost of new connections; which is mitigated very effectively (for web apps) by the connection pooling on `SqlConnection`.

Comment: so then where would you store it?  open/closing per call?

Comment: I would, yes. If you have a few tightly-coupled operations at the data layer, then you might share it...

Comment: isn't it an expensive object like the session object in nhibernate?